# bind to collection with a null object and a 'varies' object

Tags: silverlight, binding, itemssource

I have a combobox with the ItemsSource bound to a list of objects. I need to add a 'None' option and a 'Varies' option.

What is the best way to add those options to my lists?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just put them in the list?

Comment: What would the type be? How would my viewmodel handle the occurrence of those objects?

Comment: What is the type of the objects in the list?  That sounds like app specific logic.  Post some more details as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have a list of parts. The user picks a part from the list. I suppose the best option is to make some 'dummy' parts that represent 'None' and 'Varies' and stick those in the list too. I guess I was looking for something else.

Comment: Have you ever seen an application that allows the user to use one properties to panel to set properties on all of the selected objects at once? And, if the values vary across the objects, the panel shows '_Varies_' as the selected option. I want that.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/MultiSelComboBox.aspx

Comment: No, that is a combobox that offers multi-selection. I want a combobox that offers single selection, but gets and sets properties on multiple objects, and in the case where not all objects share the same value, the option 'varies' displays.

Comment: So when would None be selected?

Comment: See below. @Josh nailed it on the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CompositeCollection to join the static 'None' and 'Varies' to the other dynamic items in your combobox ItemsSource.  Here's a link for the CompositeCollection:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx.

If you're using something other than a string or a value type in your ItemsSource you will need to make dummy objects representing the None or Varies selections.  Then bind to the SelectedItem property and perform the required additional logic to handle the their special conditions.

If you're just doing value types or strings, you can bind to the SelectedValue property and handle their specific conditions.

Comment: I had tagged this as a WPF issue. It's actually a Silverlight issue. CompositeCollection is not available. I am going with the dummy data. http://forums.silverlight.net/t/233984.aspx/1?Alternative+to+CompositeCollection

Comment: Composite collection is not available in silverlight.